# Замена цвета и резинка

Tags: xcode, objective-c, graphics

День добрый. Сейчас разбирюсь и рисовалкой и нарисовались 3 вопроса

> if (!okButtonBOOL) { UITouch *touch =
> [touches anyObject]; CGPoint
> currentPoint = [touch
> locationInView:self];
>
> UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
> CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0.0f,
> 0.0f,
>                              self.frame.size.width,
>                              self.frame.size.height);
> [_drawImage.image
> drawInRect:drawRect];
> CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
> kCGLineCapRound);
> CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
> 5.0); CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
> CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
> lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
> CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
> currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
> CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
> _drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
> UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
>
> lastPoint = currentPoint; }

1. На iPhone5 когда рисую линию чувство как будто у меня экран от iPhone3g, видны пиксели, причем жутко. Как с этим бороться ?
    ===== РЕШЕНО ===== Спасибо [[@aknew](/users/2088/aknew)](/users/2088/aknew)
   нужно использовать UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 2.0f); вместо UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
2. Я нарисовал 10  отдельных линий, как нме изменить их цвет?
    ===== РЕШЕНО =====

   > ```
   >         UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
   >         UIImage *image = _drawImage.image;// Image to mask with
   >         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size,
   > ```
   >
   > NO, image.scale);
   >             CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   >             [color setFill];
   >             CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0,
   > image.size.height);
   >             CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
   >             CGContextClipToMask(context,
   > CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width,
   > image.size.height), [image CGImage]);
   >             CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width,
   > image.size.height));
   >
   > ```
   >         UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   >
   >         _drawImage.image = coloredImg;
   >
   >         UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   > ```
3. Как сделать Clear линию ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. нужно использовать UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 2.0f); вместо UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);, только учтите есть ограничения по версии оси - уточните их на всякий случай, хотя это кажется 4.х только относится, а то и еще раньше
2. в таком виде - никак, картинка отрисовалась и после этого хранится в виде растрового изображения, а не набора линий, нужно как-то записывать параметры линий и при изменении цвета/очистке линии перерисовывать картинку. Возможно и есть уже готовые фреймворки по работе с векторной графикой, но тут я пас -не приходилось их как-то использовать. Собственно, все растровые редакторы тоже не позволяют менять цвет линий, только если заменить все вхождения определенного цвета на другой
3. Если под стиранием подразумевается отмена отрисовки линии - все как в предыдущем пункте, если же именно стирание - с ходу не готов ответить на данный вопрос. Как вариант может помочь закраска цветом фона  - т.е. по мере движения ластика вы поверх отрисованной картинки рисуете линию цвета фона (как опять таки работают все растовые редакторы - что пейнт, что фотошоп, только у них это не фон а второй цвет)